# Can I manually trip setOnLoadCallback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a website that uses Google Charts, and I've recently adding smooth page transitions to made navigating it a little more fun, but due to these smooth changes, `setOnLoadCallback` is not firing, so my charts aren't being drawn.

This line is never fired:
`google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`

Is there a way to manually trip this so that chart is drawn?

You can see the site here:

http://www.gta-bawsaq-billionaire.com/

If you navigate to a stock page, you'll see no chart appears, but if you refresh then it will.

For example, navigate to http://www.gta-bawsaq-billionaire.com/stock/ps3/BET by clicking **PS3** and then **Betta Pharmacuticals**. No chart will appear. Click the above link, however (or press F5 when on the page) and the chart will appear.

Comment: Has google a function called onLoadCallback()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the offending line from:

`google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`

to

`$(document).ready(drawChart);`

And then using this bit of code to manually fire `$(document).ready()` (taken from [here](http://www.parsonsprojects.co.uk/smoothstate-wordpress/));

```
;(function($, undefined) {
    var isFired = false;
    var oldReady = jQuery.fn.ready;
    $(function() {
        isFired = true;
        $(document).ready();
    });
    jQuery.fn.ready = function(fn) {
        if(fn === undefined) {
            $(document).trigger('_is_ready');
            return;
        }
        if(isFired) {
            window.setTimeout(fn, 1);
        }
        $(document).bind('_is_ready', fn);
    };
})(jQuery);
```